# Only 8 months remaining in Blue card expiry, am I still eligible to go to Germany?

Tags: germany, blue-card

I was in Berlin in 2020 for 6 months but since the pandemic went from bad to worse I had to come to India to help my family.

During these 6 months, I was able to get Blue Card.

No, since I came back I resigned from a German company and joined an employer in India.

Now, I want to go back to Germany to search job, am I eligible?

Do I need to get stamping again?

Comment: Even if the question does not belong here and shout be moved to Expatriates SE, to make it short: Your Blue Card expires if you leave Germany for more than 12 months, so it is likely not valid anymore.

Comment: How can I move the question there? Expires mean I need to follow same process from scratch? Apply for Job Seeker >  Get Job > Get Blue card , right?

Comment: @jarnbjo can you share some source to read, about what you are saying?

Answer (score 2):

Independent of the remaining period on your Blue Card: If you left Germany in 2020 and haven't been there since, your Blue Card has expired and is no longer valid.

All German residence permits will eventually expire if you stay for an extended period of time abroad. In general, you can not leave Germany for more than 6 months, but for the Blue Card, the period is extended to 12 months.

Source: [Residence Act §51](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1050)